# Restoring hidden apps to a home screen

Tags: iphone, ios

I used up all the space on my 11 home screens with apps, then installed another app (which can only be found through search as it's installed 'offscreen'). To make more space, I put a lot of different apps into folders.

**How do I restore the hidden app back to a home screen?**

If I reset the home screens then my folders are lost and an app will be off screen again, and I'd be back to square one.

Running iPhone 4, iOS 4.3.

Comment: What version of iOS are you running?  What device? Have you tried locating the app in iTunes after syncing and re-arranging from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually an easier way to do this, and it doesn't require connecting to iTunes.

If you have extra space on a screen, as it sounds like the OP had after arranging their apps into groups (folders), all you need to do is to reboot your phone, and the app will reappear in one of the blank spaces on the screen.

You can use either a soft reboot or a hard (RAM) reboot to do this, so it's as complicated as turning off your phone and turning it back on again.

If anyone would like to test this, I have a known, reproducible bug in iOS 6 for throwing an icon "off-screen" that I can share.

Comment: I've tried this several times and it doesn't fix the problem (iPhone 6, iOS 8.3). I have a folder with a couple of contact apps that I must have accidentally hidden when the phone was in my pocket and I can't get it back. The apps still appear in Spotlight so I know they're still there.

Answer (score 3):

You can rearrange your applications from within iTunes and then Sync.

Connect your iPhone and open iTunes, then click on your phone and then Apps:

[image]

Also, consider using [folders](http://www.apple.com/ios/) to organize your apps.

> Organize apps into folders with drag-and-drop simplicity. Get faster access to your favorites and browse and manage thousands of apps.

Comment: I meant folders when I said 'grouped apps together'

Comment: @Pacifika in either case, folders or no folders, the only way to bring it back is to move it forwards in the pages with iTunes.

Comment: Actually, if @Pacifika arranged everything on the iDevice and would go to move around things on iTunes and sync, everything done on the iDevice would be lost. And, like @level42 said in the other answer, this is not the only way to bring it back. Besides all that, granted, it is the easiest possible way to fix the issue.

Comment: @cawas I assume @Pacifika already has iTunes and the iDevice in Sync. This is just a matter of rearranging them so new space will be created. It's true that if you rearrange in the device (by creating an empty page) new things will fit and appear. But there's a limit to the number of items Folders can have, a limit of Folders per page and a limit of pages. :) (A folder can have 12 items, 16 folders per page, 11 pages == 2112 visible apps? (plus 4 on the dock). Maybe i'm off but that's the idea. Now @pacifika sure has a lot of stuff! :)

Comment: Yeah, the numbers are probably right. But I guess Pacifica   reached less than 300 apps, with just a few folders, which is already a lot. Once you get to 2112 then you have to either delete, jailbreak or *spotlight search* for the app. Still I insist - iTunes is not the only way to bring it back.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any critical data in that app, the easiest way to do this is probably to uninstall it (uncheck it in the Apps list in iTunes under your iPhone, then sync) and reinstall it (recheck it, resync).

Answer (score 1):

If you grouped enough apps together for create a blank page in the middle, the iPhone will condense the pages bring all the apps over one page.

For example if you freed up page 9 (made it blank) everything on page 10 would now be on page 9, everything on page 11 would now be on page 10, and everything that was hidden off screen on the missing page 12, should now be on page 11.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It might sound stupid but sometimes when you re-load your new iPhone the apps get put on the farthest screens while your second screen might only show an app or two.  Swipe over and your apps will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Reset home screen layout;under the reset tab.

Comment: _If I reset the home screens then my folders are lost and an app will be off screen again, and I'd be back to square one._

Answer (score 0):

Creating a space on the home screen where the app disappeared and then turning off my phone worked perfectly. The missing app was right there. All good

Answer (score 0):

Go into the App Store, click on Purchases at the top of the page, and you will see all the apps you ever downloaded. Click on any of these to restore the selected app's icon to your home screen.